# Database exclusivity design

Tags: database-design

I am trying to build a tournament scheduler application. In the database I have one specific problem. I have the following database tables:

- Hour (which is connected to the days that the tournament will run)
- Official (the person who will officiate the match)
- Field (the field on which the match will be played)

The problem I'm having is that if I 'connect' (use the PK of the above tables as a FK in my 'Match' table directly) I can have one official who can officiate two games at the same time OR I can have multiple officials who officiate on one and the same pitch at the same time OR I can have multiple matches on the same time on the same pitch.

**How would I go about fixing this from a design point of view?** I realise I could just limit the options one can choose programmatically but I'm really interested in how you can fix this from a design point of view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enforce the rules programatically either:

a) within your application programming language

b) in the database using triggers/functions/procedures